# Specific query with "where" and "whereHas(Relation)"

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Code looks like this:

```
$query = Course::where('author_id', Auth::user()->id)->where(
            'name',
            'ilike',
            '%' . $this->searchForm . '%'
        )->orWhere(
            'description',
            'ilike',
            '%' . $this->searchForm . '%'
        )->with(['author', 'photo', 'subscriptions', 'FAQs', 'favourites'])->orderBy($this->sortBy[0], $this->sortBy[1])
            ->withCount('subscriptions', 'FAQs');
        $courses = $query->paginate($this->paginate_courses, ['*'], '1page');

        $favourites = $query->whereHas('favourites', function ($query) {
            $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
        })->paginate($this->paginate_courses, ['*'], '2page');
```

Favourites works ok without querying about searchForm.
Is there any way to make query works? With querying search form and relationship check? I've tried whereHas && whereRelation - and result is the same - $favourites contains all $courses.
I can make it with filter() or reject() - it actually works (except pagination aspect).